# Why lines of RTL language are broken in Android WebView but not in browsers?

Tags: android, webview, arabic, right-to-left, persian

I have a web app. In Android WebView the lines are broken even though the whole  is dedicated to that line of text. The line is displayed perfectly fine in browsers. What should I check? Is this WebView issue or am I doing something wrong? 
(I should note that this is only the case for RTL languages. I have no problem with English lines)

[image]

Comment: Can you post the `html` code please? Maybe this helps to find the issue because we can try it out ourselves.

Comment: Sure:     <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShouldHavePhotos)@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ShouldHavePhotos)</div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>